# how to remove _layout for admin dashboard

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to exclude _layout for specific admin dashboard View. The only way I'm aware is with JS to hide those divs. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the razor page for which you don't want to use a layout, you can do:

```cs
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude Layout from view temporarily, you can return view from a controller action using this code

```
if(...) return PartialView("name",model);
return View("name",model)
```

When you return a partial view, it will show only a view, no a layout

If your wont to exclude a layout  permanenly for some views, you can use this code inside of the view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

but don't forget that a Layout usually contains the most of Javascript and css libraries. So it is better to create a special layout for some views.
or you can use ViewStart page

```
@{  
    string CurrentName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]);  
    dynamic Layout;  
    switch (CurrentName)  
    {  
        case "User":  
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";  
            break;  
        default:  
            //Admin layout  
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayoutPage.cshtml";  
            break;  
    }  
}
```